# How to make critical editions with marginal numbers and apparatus immediately below the text?

Tags: minipage, reledmac, critical

I am preparing an edition of scholia and I would like to create a critical edition (using ednotes or reledmac) with the critical notes immediately following the edited text and with marginal numbers.

The best way that I have found to get the notes to immediately follow the text - that is, not at the bottom of the page - is to use a minipage. But minipage does not allow marginal line numbers.

Has anyone produced a solution for this situation?

(New - following the suggestion below to use reledmac with ledgroup:) Using reledmac's ledgroup I can get close to what I want, but I can't get the notes to work in paragraph form. When I use \Xarrangment{paragraph}, it sends the notes to the bottom of the page and garbles them. When I comment out \Xarrangment{paragraph} the notes look fine, but of course they are not in paragraph form. Are others getting this behavior as well?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}
\lineation{pstart} 
\linenummargin{outer}

\begin{document}

\begin{ledgroup}
\beginnumbering
\Xarrangement{paragraph}%twocol, paragraph
\Xafternumber{1em}
\firstlinenum{2}\linenumincrement{2}
\pstart 
\noindent
 blah blah blah blah blurb blurb
\edtext{blurb blurb}{\Afootnote{blah blah \emph{codd.}}}
blah blah blah blah blah
\edtext{blurb}{\Afootnote{blah \textbf{A}}}
blah blah 
\edtext{blurb}{\Afootnote{blah \textbf{A}}}
blah blah blah blah
\edtext{blurb blurb}{\Afootnote{ blah \textbf{B}}}  blah blah blah blah blah.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{ledgroup}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want to achieve? Otherwise, understanding your question is a bit like the story of the blind men trying to describe an elephant (except for professional book designers who work on critical editions, of course, but they are pretty hard to find). A MWE of your partial solution would be very helpful as well, otherwise this looks rather like a "do it for me" question, which isn't really on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reledmac, you can use the ledgroup environment

```
\begin{ledgroup}
\beginnumbering
\pstart your first § \pend
\pstart your second § \pend
etc
\endnumbering
\end{ledgroup}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the notes to a ledgroup appear in paragraph form? (I can't fit a minimal example in this comment section...)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Or, maybe you need `\Xarrangement{paragraph}` or / `arrangementX{paragraph}`

Comment: When I comment in \Xarrangment{paragraph}, it sends the notes to the bottom of the page and garbles them.

Comment: I gave a minimal example of what I am doing in the original question, because it won't fit here.

Comment: that is a bug. Please open an issue on github.

Comment: As explained in the github issue, it is finally, not a bug. You must call the settings command before the ledgroup. Cf https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commit/4d1a9b7c30a8d7262c218ca97393a96a5df59eda

Comment: Great! Thanks. Finally, it seems not to work with the bidi package. Is this a problem with reledmac or with bidi?

Comment: with the interaction between twice... but the bidi maintener never answer to my question.